# dagger2 error "android.app.Application cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method"

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

I'm trying to implement dagger2 in my project, but I'm faced with an error "**android.app.Application cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method**".

Here's my code:

**App.java**

```
package com.poppmedia.wallpaperautomaton;

import android.app.Application;

import com.poppmedia.wallpaperautomaton.di.DaggerAppComponent;

import dagger.android.AndroidInjector;
import dagger.android.DaggerApplication;

/**
 * The Android {@link Application}.
 */
public class App extends DaggerApplication {
    @Override
    protected AndroidInjector<? extends DaggerApplication> applicationInjector() {
        return DaggerAppComponent.builder().create(this);
    }
}
```

**di/AppModule.java**

```
package com.poppmedia.wallpaperautomaton.di;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;

import javax.inject.Singleton;

import dagger.Binds;
import dagger.Module;

/**
 * Provider application-wide dependencies.
 */
@Module
public interface AppModule {
    @Binds
    @Singleton
    Context bindContext(Application application);
}
```

**di/AppComponent.java**

```
package com.poppmedia.wallpaperautomaton.di;

import com.poppmedia.wallpaperautomaton.App;

import javax.inject.Singleton;

import dagger.Component;
import dagger.android.AndroidInjector;
import dagger.android.support.AndroidSupportInjectionModule;

/**
 * Injects application dependencies.
 */
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class,
        AppModule.class,
})
public interface AppComponent extends AndroidInjector<App> {
    @Component.Builder
    abstract class Builder extends AndroidInjector.Builder<App> {}
}
```

**di/TestClassModule.java**

```
package com.poppmedia.wallpaperautomaton.di;

import android.content.Context;

import com.poppmedia.wallpaperautomaton.TestClass;

import javax.inject.Singleton;

import dagger.Module;
import dagger.Provides;

@Module
public class TestClassModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    TestClass provideTestClass(Context context) {
        return new TestClass(context);
    }
}
```

**di/TestClassComponent.java**

```
package com.poppmedia.wallpaperautomaton.di;

import com.poppmedia.wallpaperautomaton.TestClass;

import javax.inject.Singleton;

import dagger.Component;

@Singleton
@Component(modules = { AppModule.class, TestClassModule.class })
public interface TestClassComponent {
    TestClass getTestClass();
}
```

**TestClass.java**

```
package com.poppmedia.wallpaperautomaton;

import android.content.Context;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class TestClass {
    private Context mContext;

    @Inject
    public TestClass(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: I neither see you binding your `Application` in a component builder, nor adding it to some module, providing it there.

Comment: I tried add the following:

**di/AppModule.java**
`@Binds
@Singleton
Application bindApplication(Application application);`

**di/AppComponent.java**
`Application getApplication();`

And I get a dependency cycle error.

Comment: @DanielGorgan Try it with `@Binds Application bindApplication(App app);` such that you are binding the general `Application` object to your custom implementation you call `App`. You can take or leave the `@Singleton` but I'd leave it out—it's not helping you here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your specific case, you're missing:

```
@Binds Application bindApplication(App app);
```

This is important because dagger.android will automatically include a binding to *the specific Application, Activity, Fragment, Service, BroadcastReceiver, etc subclass* but not the *general object*. (You'd be able to inject *App* but not *Application*, and *YourActivity* but not *Activity*.) If you want to indicate to dagger.android that it should fulfill requests for Application using your App instance, you have to include a binding as above.

Generally speaking, this is a pretty safe thing to do for Application, Activity, Service, and BroadcastReceiver, but not Fragment (native or in the compat libraries); this is because dagger.android respects nested fragments, and in that case it would be ambiguous which Fragment to inject.

Though you can provide the Application through a Module and instance field as in [luffy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47988888/1426891), this is more boilerplate than you need, and is also less optimized: Dagger will write code to call your `@Provides` method, whereas you can declaratively tell Dagger to reuse an existing binding using `@Binds` or write a `static @Provides` method that avoids invoking the call on an instance.

See [the Dagger advantages of `@Binds`](https://google.github.io/dagger/faq.html#why-is-binds-different-from-provides) and [the Android advantages of static dispatch](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#PreferStatic).

Comment: ```@Binds Application bindApplication(App app);
``` which class should it be?

Comment: If you are using a custom subclass of Application, as Daniel does with "App" above, that's the class you need to bind Application to if you want to be able to inject it.

Comment: where do you add this binds?

Comment: @jonney In a Module listed on your application's @Component. The one in the original question is AppComponent. Remember that the line is unique to the name `App` from the question, and that you should replace it with the name of your custom Application subclass.

Answer (score 0):

In AppModule, you @Binds a Application, but Application is not provide by any other module.

Because the Application is created by Android framework, you should let AppModule provide the Application from outside.

```
@Module
public class AppModule {
    private Application mApp;
    public AppModule(Application app) {
        mApp = app
    }
    @Singleton
    Context provideContext() {
        return mApp
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not the best way to do it: There exists a binding for `App` already, and for simple bindings like this it is preferable to use `@Binds` or `@BindsInstance`.