# How can I inject params from bundles at runtime with dagger.android?

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I'm working on wrapping my head around `Dagger 2` and I've came upon a situation that I'm not really sure how to properly solve.  I'm using `dagger.android` to set up `subcomponents` for each of my activities and fragments, where each subcomponent has a presenter with it's own dependencies.

The problem is that one fragment should display info fetched from the web, so I'm passing in a `URL` to the fragment to tell it what to display.  But I'm not sure how to get `Dagger` too resolve the dependency on fragment load.  I thought I needed a `subcomponent builder`, but that's apparently redundant as the compiler message is telling me it need the `URL` from a `Provides` method.  I've also set up a qualifier for the `URL` and annotated a method in the fragment with it.  I thought `Dagger` might pick it up, but I was wrong.  Can someone give me an idea as to how best handle this situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I am not wrong you are trying to provide `url` dependency in `Fragment` which is provided via `Bundle`. In that case add `Provides` method in `Module` which will take `Fragment` as parameter. As `Fragment` instance is on the `graph` it will automatically satisfy.

**Fragment:**

```
@Inject
String url;

public static DetailFragment newInstance() {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("url", "http://stackoverflow.com/");
    DetailFragment fragment = new DetailFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this);
    super.onAttach(context);

    printInfo();
}


public void printInfo(){
    if (url == null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Url is null");
    }else {
        Log.i(TAG, "Url: " + url);
    } 
}
```

**Module:**

```
@Module
public class DetailFragmentModule {

    @Provides
    String provideUrl(DetailFragment detailFragment){
      Bundle bundle = detailFragment.getArguments();
      String url = bundle.getString("url");
      return url;
   }

   @Provides
   DetailFragmentView provideDetailFragmentView(DetailFragment detailFragment){
     return detailFragment;
   }
}
```

As you are injecting `url` in `DetailFragment` it will go to `provideUrl` method and satisfy `DetailFragment` and it will return `url` from `Bundle`.

This worked for me. :)

Comment: Huh, interesting.  Yup, you're right in what I'm attempting to do.  I didn't know that the fragment was available in the object graph, I must have missed that in the documentation.  While I can't try this out until later, I'm going to go ahead and mark it as the answer, thanks!

Comment: +1; this is the right answer. Just remember that though your specific Fragment subclass (DetailFragment) and Activity subclass are injectable, there's no binding to superclasses like Fragment or Activity themselves...at least, without [a binding in a Module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48004539/1426891).

Comment: That makes sense.  Out of curiosity, is this the intended method by design, or more of a work around?  I don't remember seeing anything like this in the docs, and while I understand it it wasn't immediately apparent to me this is what you should do (hence the question, obviously ☺️).

Comment: Really good answer! My only problem now is that now the key used for the item you put inside the bundle (bundle.putString(`key`, `value`) could not longer be private within the fragment as you have to use the `key` for the module. Now to avoid this, you'll have to create methods abstracting getting of the value from the bundle but that is then added boiler plate code. :(